# is possible to set up more than one Dynamic list filter in Sharepoint list web component?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am totally new to Sharepoint,
I am trying to create a filter control that can filter multiple values on the target list.
I have 2 lists one is RoadMap and the other one is RoadMap-Filter
RoadMap contains all the information for certain products and RoadMap-filter contain the only two of the category values that I would like to use to be able to filter the RoadMap.

the two categories of values are "Status" & "Product" those values are present in the main list in the respective columns

So when I select from the filter "Product 1" > "In Development" I would like to see all the "Product 1" that are also "In Development" and so on

To be more clear I would like to achieve a similar result to this one https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=

explanatory gif
https://i.gyazo.com/0e5b44f008e4c20d8c2b00f06d8475d9.gif

from the gif you can see that the product got filtered but I would like also an extra filter based on the status of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your list setup so I will assume you are trying to apply multiple filters on a SharePoint List. For that is doable and very straightforward. Simply filter the column with the value you like just like the gif below.
[image]

**Update:**

As you want to filter a list based on another list, then you can connect web parts to do so. For the deatailed steps, have a check on the last part (**Filter a list based on a selection in another list or library**) of this doc :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the my question with a gif. what I would like to have is another list to manage the filter options.